# Android Service is not running in background properly

Tags: android, service

As soon as i open my application, i start this line :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

**And here's my IntentService Class:**

```
public class MyIntentService extends Service {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static String prefName = "SecretFile";
    public static String version = "56";
    public final static int uniqueID = 1394885;



public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        version = prefs.getString("Version", "1");
        System.out.println(version);
        calllsharedprefs();
        new loadSomeStuff().execute();
    }

public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//starting script
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    json.getString("Version");
                    Editor editoi = prefs.edit();
                    editoi.putString("Version", json.getString("Version"));
//finishing script
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (prefs.getString("Version", "1").equals(version)) {
            } else {
                System.out.println(prefs.getString("Version", "1"));
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.cancel(uniqueID);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyIntentService.this, Drawer.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        MyIntentService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                String body = "New Updates are available!";
                String title = "Price list changed";
                Notification n = new Notification(
                        R.drawable.about, body,
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                n.setLatestEventInfo(MyIntentService.this, title, body, pi);
                n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
                nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
                version = prefs.getString("Version", "1");
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, i'm getting the Version field from a table in phpMyAdmin, if the version code is the same dont send notification if it's not send a notification and set it as the same as phpmyadmin version, **BUT** however when i open my application the code starts and it sends me a notification, but when i re-edit the value from the table to set it like 9, it doesn't work it doesn't send anotificaiton again! what to do? Thanks =)

Comment: you are calling >>loadSomeStuff().execute();  in oncreate.
it will execute only once, and do whatever you asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling >>`loadSomeStuff().execute();`  in oncreate.
it will execute only once, and do whatever you asked it to do.

Either you start this `IntentService` each time you edit the value or you do it in `Activity` it self. It seems you dont need an Service, You can show notification from `Activity` it self.

Comment: how can i start IntentService each time i edit the value from phpmyadmin??

Comment: can i do an alarm manager in OnCreate and every 12 hours it refresh??

Comment: Yes you can start AlarmManager. Problem is that your service is not getting notified after you edit things. You have to add mechanism to read the data after some interval or something like that

Comment: can you rate my question so i can rate up your answer? it requires 15 points